# Обмен значениями между двумя экземплярами классов в Unity(C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Приветствую. Допустим у нас есть класс, содержащий различные значения и публичную структуру:

public class Item : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Sprite ItemSprite;
public int stack;
public int maxStack;

/// <summary>
/// ID используется для определения места в инвентаря (от 0 до суммарного количества всех ячеек)
/// </summary>
public int ID;

/// <summary>
/// ItemID - это личный номер каждого вида предмета, по нему определяется идентичность объекта
/// </summary>
public int ItemID;


[Header("Настройки Предмета-Модуля")]


public enum BonusID
{
    None,
    MaxShield,
    MaxEnergy,
    MaxHealth,
    Speed,
    ShiftSpeed,
    RotationSpeed,
    EnergyPlus,
}
public enum BonusType
{
    None,
    Plus,
    Per_Cent,
}

public Bonus[] ItemBonuses;

private void Awake()
{
    ItemBonuses = new Bonus[0];
}

[System.Serializable]
public struct Bonus
{
    /// <summary>Кол-во бонуса. </summary>
    public float Value;
    /// <summary>На что именно влияет бонус. </summary>
    public BonusID ID;
    /// <summary>Бонус обычный или в процентах. </summary>
    public BonusType Type;

    /// <summary>
    /// Задаём параметры нового бонуса.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Кол-во нового бонуса.</param>
    /// <param name="id">На что будет влиять новый бонус.</param>
    /// <param name="type">Как будет влиять новый бонус (Процентный бафф или обычный)</param>
    public Bonus (float value, BonusID id, BonusType type)
    {
        Value = value;
        ID = id;
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

Создаём 2 экземпляра класса (Item1 и Item2) путём создания 2-ух GameObject-ов и повесив на них наш скрипт. Теперь перед нами стоит задача: нам нужно обменять значения этих экземпляров между собой (Item1 = Item2; Item2 = Item1). Сделал это вот таким способом: (Вызывается при нажатии на кнопку UI Button)

```
(Класс)Item tempItem = item1; //Это локальная переменная.
item1 = item2;
item2 = tempItem;
```

Но вот уж незадача: Не произошло ничего: Не изменились ни параметры экземпляров, ни параметры структуры(в данном примере структура не используется, т.к. создан пустой массив, так что это не страшно) и при этом Unity не сказала не слова (Ошибок нет).

Решил копать глубже и передавать значения напрямую (item1.param = item2.param) и тоже ничего не добился. Я думаю ошибка в том, что Unity не позволяет создать экземпляр класса с помощью "new", для этого нужен GameObj со скриптом, однако tempItem создаётся только в скрипте. Но в таком случае получится каша с кучей временных GameObject-ов, что, согласитесь, тоже не вариант. Так в чём же может быть ошибка и как её решить?

Comment: В какой момент инициализируется действие обмена данными (столкновение, триггер, нажатие на кнопку и пр)? Какими именно данными надо обменяться? В каком скрипте сейчас происходит обмен (можно его в вопрос добавить)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Класс)Item tempItem = item1; //Это локальная переменная.
item1 = item2;
item2 = tempItem;
```

Думаю, вы просто не совсем понимаете, что происходит в коде выше.
tempItem, item1 и item2 - это не объекты, а ссылки на объекты, которые лежат в куче. Т.е. строчками выше вы никак не изменили объекты, а просто поменяли полям-ссылкам объекты, на которые они указывают.

На счёт создания с помощью new - вы почти правы. Unity не позволяет делать этого исключительно для тех классов, которые наследуются от MonoBehaviour, т.к. монобех крепко завязан на GameObject. Когда вы пытаетесь это сделать вам выдаётся warning (предупреждение с жёлтым восклицательным знаком) о том, что так делать нельзя, а стоит использовать AddComponent().

По примеру кода выше вы могли бы заменить значения вот так:

```
var temp = item2.param;
item2.param = item1.param;
item1.param = temp;
```

т.е. кешировать именно структуру. А не создавать новую ссылку.